# Strange failure message (extra params) when verifying with spyk and coVerify

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I have an integration test where I am passing a spied Retrofit to my repository:

```
val apiSpy = spyk(PvApiService.getInstance())
val expectedTokenLength = 1290 // by definition

test("Token can be refreshed") {
    val repo = Repository(apiSpy)
    repo.reset()
    repo.refreshToken() // Suspends, run on IO thread
    coVerify (exactly = 1){apiSpy.tokenRetrofitService.getApiToken(any(), any()) }
    repo.tokenAvailable shouldBe true
    repo.token.length shouldBe expectedTokenLength
}
```

This fails verification on the spy with the following message (note that the other tests pass, which means that the call was actually made!):

```
Verification failed: call 2 of 2: PvApiTokenService(child of #2#3).getApiToken(any(), any(), any())) was not called
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 2 of 2: PvApiTokenService(child of #2#3).getApiToken(any(), any(), any())) was not called
```

My corresponding unit test for the repository, using a mock, rather than a spy, behaves as expected:

```
val mockApi = mockk<PvApiService>(relaxed = true)
val testToken = "a token"

test("Token can be refreshed") {
    coEvery { mockApi.tokenRetrofitService.getApiToken(any(), any()) } returns testToken
    val repo =  Repository(mockApi, ProjectConfig.testDispatcherProvider)
    repo.refreshToken()
    coVerify (exactly = 1){ mockApi.tokenRetrofitService.getApiToken(any(), any()) }
    repo.token shouldBe testToken
    repo.tokenAvailable shouldBe true
}
```

I do not understand the failure when using the spy.  I am verifying `getApiToken(any(), any())` (i.e. `any()` two times), while the failure message refers to `getApiToken(any(), any(), any()))` (i.e. `any()` *three* times).

What have I done, that is making MockK try to verify the call on the spy with an additional parameter?

Edit: I have now added a question to the MockK issue tracker to try to understand this behaviour!  https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer, this behaviour is confirmed by other users, and is now being tracked as a bug by the MockK project: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/554

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use `UnconfinedTestDispatcher()`.
This worked for me very well.

Comment: Why do you suggest this? How does it resolve the problem I specified?